# How to display Base64 images in asp.net web forms

Tags: html, asp.net, image, base64

I'm having trouble displaying a Base64 image inline or in css-file.
i'm using vs-2017.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>Display Image</title>
    <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
  <body>
    <img class="slide1"  alt="" />       
 </body>
```

In that CSS file some simple code is written that loads the image.

```
   .slide1 {
     background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo)
     }
```

the problem is the image can not loaded or display .
any advice

Comment: I think `iVBORw0KGgo` isn't base64 string for image...